# Copying file from one location to another location using jets3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

In my application I use `Amazon S3` server to store data. I am trying to move a specific file from one location to another location  using the `jets3` api as follows:

```
public void moveFile(String currentPath, String newPath, String fileName, boolean overWrite) throws FileException
    {
        S3Service s3Service = null;
        try
            {
                s3Service = getS3Service();
                String bucketFolderPath = "test-site/files/doc-lib/2015/07/16/09/05/46/552/v-6";
                String currentFolderPath = "test-site/files/doc-lib/2015/07/16/09/05/46/552/head";
                S3Bucket writeToLocation = s3Service.createBucket(this.bucketName + "/" + bucketFolderPath);
                S3Bucket readFromLocation = s3Service.createBucket(this.bucketName + "/" + currentFolderPath);
                try 
                {
                    s3Service.moveObject(currentFolderPath, "Eclipse-Shortcuts.pdf", bucketFolderPath, new S3Object("Eclipse-Shortcuts.pdf"), overWrite);
                } 
                catch (ServiceException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
            {
                throw new FileException("Could not write the file to the repository", ex);
            }
        catch (S3ServiceException ex)
            {
                throw new FileException("Could not write the file to the repository", ex);
            }
        finally
            {
                shutDownService(s3Service);
            }
    }
```

Here `Eclipse-Shortcuts.pdf` is the name of the file which I am trying to copy. 
When this method is executed, I am getting the following error:

> org.jets3t.service.ServiceException: S3 Error Message. PUT '/test-site/files/doc-lib/2015/07/16/09/05/46/552/v-6/Eclipse-Shortcuts.pdf' on Host 's3.amazonaws.com' @ 'Tue, 21 Jul 2015 06:11:55 GMT' -- ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: `AccessDenied`Access Denied3C5B8A31DC582D13ulPMuZ7PqE9uUMje6/5Y/N7mEppYlr8BPHr60ixVwcy1LOj0sszhEDYxbEg+vypY
>           at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:453)
>           at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestPut(RestStorageService.java:961)
>           at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.copyObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:1831)
>           at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.copyObject(StorageService.java:873)
>           at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.copyObject(StorageService.java:918)
>           at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.moveObject(StorageService.java:967)
>           at com.smartwcm.filestore.impl.FileStoreImpl.moveFile(FileStoreImpl.java:380)
>           at com.smartwcm.core.file.service.impl.FileUploadServiceImpl.moveFile(FileUploadServiceImpl.java:189)
>           at com.smartwcm.core.simplewebcontent.service.impl.SimpleWebContentServiceImpl.moveCurrentDataForDocLibEdit(SimpleWebContentServiceImpl.java:963)

I am very new to working with the `jets3` api. In the same class where I have this code, I have a method to save a file to a specified location and that is working. Only issue is with the move part.

Comment: The error says: "ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: AccessDenied", I'll check the credentials or loging system S3 uses. Don't know how S3 works but maybe your access token has expired or something like this...

Comment: Or maybe the Bucket name contains an upper case letter or folder name contains a space? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html